# Как привязать события клик к ссылки. DOM

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Как привязать события клик к ссылки номер 2, когда первая ссылка динамическая, то есть она появляется и исчезает рандомно.

Этот скрипт должен работать с DOM, нет возможности работать с кодом.

```
<div class="a">
    <a class="href" href="#">1</a> //Рандомная ссылка
    <a class="href" href="#">2</a>
    <a class="href" href="#">3</a>
</div>

var el = document.getElementsByClassName('href')[0]; el.click();
```

Я бы посчитал количество ссылок. Если ссылок стало на одну больше, выполнил условие if, к нулю прибавил единицу. Но бывают случаи, когда ссылок стает гораздо больше, а мне необходимо привязать событие к определенной ссылки.

Comment: ничего не понятно

Comment: _мне необходимо привязать событие к определенной ссылки._ - и как ты хочешь определять _к какой именно_ ссылке надо привязывать событие?

Comment: @ Grundy, от этого я и не знаю.

Comment: Igor, мне нужно чтобы скрипт, при любых обстоятельствах, находил и нажимал на ссылку номер 2

Comment: а как определять номер ссылки?

Comment: @Sergiyss, вы говорите, что вам необходимо привязать событие к определенной ссылке. Как вы определяете эту определенную ссылку? По атрибуту `href`, по тексту ссылки?

Comment: @ Alex Zhulin, по ссылки, я не знаю как по тексту определить, потому что я указал простой пример, тем где я пытаюсь сделать, кроме названии ссылки, идет еще куча текста.

Comment: @Sergiyss, можете указать HTML ссылки? Если у нее есть хоть какой-то уникальный параметр, то к ней можно привязаться.

Comment: @Alex Zhulin У нее нет нечего уникального, только название. `<a class="flhdr" href="?wicket:interface=:2:actionPanel:damageRandomEnemyLink::ILinkListener::&amp;action=1492801800048"><img class="internalIcon" alt="" src="/images/icons/attack.png" border="0">Бить врагов </a>`

Comment: @Sergiyss - значит надо сделать ее уникальной, задав ей дополнительный специальный класс, который можно нигде не объявлять `<a class="flhdr selectme"  ...`

Comment: @Igor, dom динамическая, это игра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если только название уникально, то можно искать по названию.

```js
var link = null
  , links = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
  , searchText = 'Бить врагов ';
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  if (links[i].textContent === searchText) {
    link = links[i];
    break;
  }
}
if (link) {
  console.log('Ссылка найдена.');
  //link.click();
}
else {
  console.log('Ссылка не найдена.');
}
```

```html
<a class="flhdr" href="#">Не бить врагов</a>
<a class="flhdr" href="?wicket:interface=:2:actionPanel:damageRandomEnemyLink‌​::ILinkListener::&am‌​p;action=14928018000‌​48"><img class="internalIcon" alt="" src="/images/icons/attack.png" border="0">Бить врагов </a>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли)

Comment: А  цикл перебирает полностью всё ссылки, до тех пор, пока не найдет    в нем нужное название, а после эту ссылку заносит в переменную `link` ?

Comment: @Sergiyss, да, но можно ограничить область поиска, если бы была предоставлена часть оригинального HTML побольше.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть так:

```
$('body').on("click", 'a.href', function (e) {
    //Уточняем элемент
});
```